# NO CSS - html two divs side by side

Tags: html

Is there any possibility of creating two divs side by side in html without using css?

I could not find any solution and somehow believe, that this is not possible with pure html.

I have no chance to use css, therefore the only any solution with only html is required.

Comment: div has `display: block` by default, so you need to switch to other type of elements, such as `span`

Comment: What do you mean by "pure HTML" and "without using CSS"? Do you mean **any** CSS, such as the `style=""` attribute? Or do you mean just external CSS? What about inline `<style>`?

Comment: And **why** do you want to do this without CSS?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Dai. Inline <style> works for me. How could it leads to solve the place two divs side by side? I do not want to do it without css, but i have to. It is all about to create an html file with plotly.js.

Comment: Thank you Yegor. How to define to place two spans side by side?

Comment: each div tag automatically displays its contents on on a new line, unless you  change it from display: block to display: inline or display: inline-block.  span tags automatically display their content on the same line, unless the line needs to wrap, you add <br /> tags between two span tags, or several other means, including changing the span's display to block.  You could also use tables to show divs in different columns, but that seems like over kill.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what it means to "do it without CSS". Remember that "CSS" effectively refers to the layout system used by every web-page in a modern web-browser (and by "modern" I mean: made since 2001).

So a web-page with no explicit `style=""` attributes, no `<style>` elements and no `<link rel="stylesheet" />` elements is still using CSS: it still has the built-in user-agent stylesheet. If you use the now-obsolete presentational elements and attributes like `<font>` and `border=""` then those are converted into CSS rules by the browser. My point is that **it's impossible to not use CSS**.

...so I assume by "without CSS" you really mean "without an external stylesheet" or "without a separate `<style>` element", but in your comment reply you said that using `<style>` **is** acceptable, so I think you're confused about what your restrictions are:

> Thank you for your reply Dai. **Inline `<style>` works for me**. How could it leads to solve the place two divs side by side? I do not want to do it without css, but i have to. It is all about to create an html file with `plotly.js`

Anyway, if you **can** use `<style>`, then just do something like this:

```
<style>
#parent {
    display: flex;
}

    #parent > div {
        flex-basis: 50%;
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-shrink: 1;
    }

#left {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#right {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>

<div id="parent">

    <div id="left">

    </div>

    <div id="right">
 
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you cannot use `<style>` but you can use inline `style=""` attributes, then you can still do this:

```
<div id="parent" style="display: flex;">

    <div id="left" style="flex-basis: 50%; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; border: 1px solid red;">

    </div>

    <div id="right" style="flex-basis: 50%; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; border: 1px solid blue;">
 
    </div>
</div>
```

If you cannot add your own `<style>` elements nor `style=""` attributes then your only remaining option for laying out elements is by abusing `<table>` - but I won't post an example using `<table>` because I don't want to encourage others to do so - and because I've never encountered a system that allowed arbitrary elements but did not allow at least for custom `style=""` attributes.